# Need Help Coding a Loop Using "For" Statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I need to make a countdown happen from 10 to 0 using a loop. The loop should replace the need to repeat the code 10X. I also neeed to display the countdown to the user in the HTML. Help!

```
<script>
       
function StartTheCountdown()
{ 
     var Countdown = 10;
     // Used to keep track of actual time.
     // 1000 = 1 second because we are using milliseconds.
    var timeout = 10000;
    setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("CountDownDisplay").innerHTML = "Blastoff!";
    Countdown = Countdown - 1;
    }, timeout)
    timeout = timeout - 1000;
    // We need to do this 10 times **************************************
    setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("CountDownDisplay").innerHTML = Countdown;
    Countdown = Countdown - 1;
    }, timeout)
    timeout = timeout - 1000; 
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Check out W3schools for for loop examples in javascript https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: Please see [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](/q/3583724/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` to repeatedly call the function until `count` is zero, and then display a message.

```js
// Cache your element
const div = document.querySelector('div');

// Initialise your count to 10
function countdown(count = 10) {

  // Update your element textContent
  div.textContent = `T-minus: ${count}`;

  // Call the function again if the count
  // is greater than 0 with a decremented count
  if (count > 0) {
    setTimeout(countdown, 1000, --count);

  // Otherwise update the textContent of the
  // element with a message
  } else {
    div.textContent = 'Blast off!';
  }
}

countdown();
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)